Marklogic start Issue after Upgrading MarkLogic 10.0-9.5 to MarkLogic 11.3.1 in RHEL 8.8
I'm unable to start MarkLogic 11.3.1 after upgrading from MarkLogic 10.0-9.5 in AWS, and I'm encountering the following error. But Marklogic 10.0-9.5 run perfectly in the same AWS instance.

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was
deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future
release.
Set configuration: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_MDB_TYPE=""
Set configuration: AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
Set configuration: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_ZONE="us-east-1b"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_HOSTNAME="xx.xx.xx.xxx"
Initialize Configuration. AWS Region: us-east-1, ZONE: us-east-1b.
INSTANCE: xxxxxxxxxx
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was
deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future
release.
Instance is not managed
Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/xvdf
Volume /dev/sdf has failed to attach - aborting
Warning: ec2-startup did not complete successfully
Check the error logs for details

this script is giving message and aborted ML startup:

Steps taken to upgrade:

Instance type: m4.xlarge
No volume was attached at the time of upgrade; only MarkLogic was upgraded.
We simply followed the steps to uninstall MarkLogic 10.0-9.5 and install MarkLogic 11.3.0.
Start MarkLogic using the command /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start.
We encountered the above mentioned error.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Also we are trying to upgrade another system but getting same issue.

Set configuration:
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.382.b05-2.el8.x86_64"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_MDB_TYPE=""
Set configuration: AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
Set configuration: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_ZONE="us-east-1a"
Set configuration: MARKLOGIC_HOSTNAME="ip-10-97-21-232.ec2.internal"
Initialize Configuration.
AWS Region: us-east-1, ZONE: us-east-1a. INSTANCE: i-00b57d0c9c5216bb4
Instance is not managed
Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/nvme1n1
UUID dev mapping:
Final dev mapping: /dev/nvme1n1
Attempting to mount EBS device /dev/sdf OS device /dev/nvme1n1 on
mountpoint /var/opt/MarkLogic
Directory /var/opt/MarkLogic has contents - skipping
Failed to mount EBS volume - aborting   Warning: ec2-startup did not
complete successfully
Check the error logs for details


What EC2 instance type are you running, and how many EBS volumes do you have? What is /dev/sdf mount and do you see any other info logged about why it isn't mounting or initializing?

I have two volume /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb but Markloigc not finding this volume.

@MadsHansen I am also getting the same issue.

Which RHEL8.8 instance type you use to install 10.0-9.5, and how did you attach the volumes? And what process did you follow to upgrade it to 11.3.1 on the same machine?  You may also want to open a Support case, to make it easier to provide info/logs and get immediate assistance.

@MadsHansen


Instance type: m4.xlarge


No volume was attached at the time of upgradation; only MarkLogic was upgraded.


We simply followed the steps to uninstall MarkLogic 10.0-9.5 and install MarkLogic 11.3.0.


Start MarkLogic using the command /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start.


We encountered the above mentioned error.




Start MarkLogic from the "/etc/" directory using the command "/etc/init.d/MarkLogic start."
MarkLogic starts, but with some warnings.
Testing has begun, but we are experiencing latency, and the system is becoming unresponsive.
Reviewing the MarkLogic logs revealed no issue found.
We also upgraded another system, but the same issue was observed.


@Arunjay please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, please share how your problem is related to programming

@NicoHaase, In my case nothing special to describe. The server was running fine on Marklogic 10 and when I tried to upgrade to Marklogic 11.3.1 on same server, I am unable to start the server. It is giving error and aborted after this message "Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/xvdf"

Have you tried starting via service MarkLogic start service script instead of the /etc/init.d script? https://docs.progress.com/bundle/marklogic-server-install-11/page/topics/procedures/starting-marklogic-server.html

@MadsHansen, we tried to start it via service MarkLogic start but it is giving the same error.

There is logic in the startup scripts that look to determine whether a host is running in EC2 and is part of a managed cluster.
In older versions of MarkLogic, it was only setting the EC2 flag if you were running Amazon Linux.
In order to prevent some of the managed node startup logic from firing, you can explicitly configure the host as NOT being a managed node.
Create a /etc/marklogic.conf file and set  to false
export MARKLOGIC_MANAGED_NODE=0

That should get you past this startup issue. Although, when EC2 integration is enabled it will expect Java to be installed and will fail to start if it can't find Java. So, it could then hit on that startup issue. You can define JAVA_HOME in /etc/marklogic.conf:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre

Or you could disable EC2 integration by setting:
export MARKLOGIC_EC2_HOST=0

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/best-practice-editing-marklogic-server-environment-variables

Thanks for the reply. I created/updated the marklogic.conf file and now I am able to start MarkLogic without any issue. But, now we have noticed the slow background warnings under ErrorLog.txt.

2024-12-02 14:39:52.998 Warning: Slow background cluster.background.clusters, 16.97 sec
2024-12-02 14:39:52.998 Warning: Slow background cluster.background.hosts.forests, 3.941 sec
2024-12-02 14:39:52.999 Warning: Slow background cluster.background.hosts.AssignmentManager.rsuite-f1, 3.004 sec

Slow background messages usually indicate that the host is busy. If it's just an isolated burst when you brought the host(s) up not something to worry about. If it's all the time, may want to look for other issues and ensure that the system is properly sized (i.e. m4.xlarge which are really small instance types). https://community.progress.com/s/article/Understanding-slow-background-messages

The latency issue persists, and the log files are displaying various other messages/notices, including 'Hung' messages, 'Memory low' warnings, slow detection of indexes for the database, and XDMP-EXTIME errors. However, we are trying to resolve this issue but the question is same setup was working with ML10.0.95 but giving issues with 11.3.1.
